# Apache POI - Formula to find maximum length of characters in a column

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

*Hi All,*

*My objective was to find the maximum length of characters in a column. To achieve that I thought of using the below piece of code but it is not providing the expected result.*

```
                String range = "MAX(LEN(A1:A3))";
                formulaCell.setCellFormula(range);
                formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(formulaCell);
```

*Below is the issue which I am facing*

*The formula given in the code is being set as **=MAX(LEN(@A1:A3))** because of which the formula returns the length of the cell in the same row where the formula is being inserted.*

*I am not sure why apache POI is adding '@' to the formula if someone please let me know if there are any alternate ways.*

[image: Excel]

Answer (score 2):

It is not `apache poi` which puts the `@` into the formula. `Excel 365` is doing this because the formula part `LEN(A1:A3)` is wrong for a normal cell formula as `LEN` only expects one parameter and not multiple or a cell range. So `MAX(LEN(A1:A3))` would must be an array formula.

So if you would set the formula as such:

```
...
String formula = "MAX(LEN(A1:A3))";
//cell.setCellFormula(formula);
CellRange cellRange = sheet.setArrayFormula(formula, CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B1"));
...
```

Then `Excel` would handle that formula correctly.

But `FormulaEvaluator` cannot evaluate such array formulas correctly. It would evaluate only `MAX(LEN(A1))`.

So if the need is that `apache poi` shall know the maximum length of characters in a column, then the only way is iterating over all rows (cells) in that column, get the length of cell contents for each cell and get the maximum.

Btw.: If someone wonders why `Excel 365` not has the need to put that formula as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and not has array markers (`{=MAX(LEN(A1:A3)}`) around that formula:

`Excel 365` has a new feature called dynamic array formulas. This feature detects array formulas - in this case because `LEN` has a cell range as the argument - and then marks such formulas as array automatically. Additional it puts a metadata information to the cell that this cell contains an array formula. So the special markers `{...}` are not more needed. But `apache poi` does not support that new feature.